# how to create an Exp(-x^2) function?

Tags: java, exp

I am using the "think java" book and I am stuck on exercise 7.6. The goal here is to write a function that can find [image]. It gives you a couple hints:

> One way to evaluate  is
>   to use the infinite series expansion:
>
> [image]
>
> In other words, we need to add up a series of terms where the ith term
>   is equal to
>
> [image]

Here is the code I came up with, but it is horribly wrong (when compared to Math.exp) for anything other than a power of 1. I don't understand why, as far as I can tell the code is correct with the formula from the book. I'm not sure if this is more of a math question or something related to how big of a number double and int can hold, but I am just trying to understand why this doesn't work.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Find exp(-x^2)");
      double x = inDouble("Enter x: ");
      System.out.println("myexp(" + -x*x + ") = " + gauss(x, 20));
      System.out.println("Math.exp(" + -x*x + ") = " + Math.exp(-x*x));
   }

   public static double gauss(double x, int n) {
      x = -x*x;
      System.out.println(x);
      double exp = 1;
      double prevnum = 1;
      int prevdenom = 1;
      int i = 1;
      while (i < n) {
         exp = exp + (prevnum*x)/(prevdenom*i);
         prevnum = prevnum*x;
         prevdenom = prevdenom*i;
         i++;
      }
      return exp;
   } // I can't figure out why this is so inacurate, as far as I can tell the math is accurate to what the book says the formula is

   public static double inDouble(String string) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print(string);
      return in.nextDouble();
   }
```

Comment: Java's ints only have 32 bits, whereas your `prevdenom` want to get as large as 19!, a 57 bit number. See what happens when you make `prevdenom` a double instead of an int.

Comment: Thank you! That worked great! I guess that makes sense then that it wasn't working as an integer because the number was too big.

Comment: Are you allowed to use machineEpsilon for doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am about to add to the comment on your question. I do this because I feel I have a slightly better implementation.

**Your approach**

Your approach is to have the function accept two arguments, where the second argument is the number of iterations. This isn't bad, but as @JamesKPolk pointed out, you might have to do some manual searching for an int (or long) that won't overflow

**My approach**

My approach would use something called the machine epsilon for a data type. The machine epsilon is the smallest number of that type (in your case, double) that is representable as that number. There exists [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Approximation) for determining what that machine epsilon is, if you are not "allowed" to access machine epsilon in the `Double` class.

There is math behind this:

The series representation for your function is [image: series representation of e^(-x^2)]
Since it is alternating series, the error term is the absolute value of the first term you choose not to include (I leave the proof to you).

What this means is that we can have an error-based implementation that doesn't use iterations! The best part is that you could implement it for floats, and data types that are "more" than doubles! I present thus:

```
public static double gauss(double x) 
{
    x = -x*x;
    double exp = 0, error = 1, numerator = 1, denominator = 1;
    double machineEpsilon = 1.0;
    // calculate machineEpsilon
    while ((1.0 + 0.5 * machineEpsilon) != 1.0)
        machineEpsilon = 0.5 * machineEpsilon;
    int n = 0; //
    // while the error is large enough to be representable in terms of the current data type
    while ((error >= machineEpsilon) || (-error <= -machineEpsilon))
    {
        exp += error;
        // calculate the numerator (it is 1 if we just start, but -x times its past value otherwise)
        numerator = ((n == 0) ? 1 : -numerator * x);
        // calculate the denominator (denominator gets multiplied by n)
        denominator *= (n++);
        // calculate error
        error = numerator/denominator;
    }
    return exp;
}
```

Let me know how this works!

Comment: Thanks, this works! It took me a while to understand it though but it makes senses